# .net remoting, delegate getting called in wrong process

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

I'm doing some tests with .net remoting and found that there is a problem with it while using delegate.

I have a single app that is both server and client itself. When a user runs the app from explorer first time, it runs as server and starts a new process as client. Both works fine. Now when user run it again while server and client processes are still running, it suppose to become client and send message to server about a new process started then terminate itself.

It is all working good except the delegate is executing in server process instead
 of client.

Here is the code.

```
    const string PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName33";
    const string OBJECT_NAME = "test";
    static RemoteObject remoteObject;
    static void RegisterClient()
    {
        IpcClientChannel chan = new IpcClientChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

        remoteObject = (RemoteObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(RemoteObject),
                string.Format("ipc://{0}/{1}", PIPE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME));
    }
    static void RegisterServer()
    {
        BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
        serverProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

        IpcServerChannel chan = new IpcServerChannel("", PIPE_NAME, serverProvider);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

        RemotingServices.Marshal(new RemoteObject(), OBJECT_NAME);
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if ((args.Length == 0 || args[0] == "s"))
        {
            try
            {
                RegisterServer();
            }
            catch (RemotingException)
            {
                // try to register it with the pipe name. If it fails, means server is already running.
                //bad idea, I know, but it's just for barebone quick test
                RegisterClient();
                remoteObject.OnNewProcessStarted("test");
                Application.Exit();
                return;
            }

            Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "c");
            Application.Run(new Form1("Server"));

        }
        else
        {
            IsClient = true;
            RegisterClient();
            remoteObject.SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStarted);

            Application.Run(new Form1("Client"));

        }
    }


    static bool IsClient = false;
    static bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Is Client : " + IsClient);//problem here, IsClient should be true
        return true;
    }
```

RemoteObject class.

```
public delegate bool OnNewProcessStartedDelegate(string text);

internal class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public OnNewProcessStartedDelegate OnNewProcessStartedHandler;
    public bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
    {
        if (OnNewProcessStartedHandler != null)
            return OnNewProcessStartedHandler(commandLine);
        return false;
    }

    public void SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStartedDelegate onNewProcessStarted)
    {
        OnNewProcessStartedHandler = onNewProcessStarted;
    }

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

PS : There can only be one server and one client.

Comment: is this condition correct?? "if ((args.Length == 0 || args[0] == "s"))"

Comment: The condition means if there is no argument or if  first argument is s then it will execute server. Did you verify arguments were more than one with first argument not being "s"?

Comment: Yes arguments and conditions are correct.

Comment: can you post what is argument you are passing when you invoke second time your application?

Comment: The whole code is already posted, please have a look.

Comment: ok...are you sure your client is not running second time? did you come to that conclusion because in output you are not seeing Client = true?

Comment: Reason I asked this question because I can see in catch block you are not setting IsClient = true like how you did in else block...Add isClient = true statement in catch block and try again

Comment: Client can only be run if there is an argument that is not `s` or server is already started. The posted code is complete, you can run it on your side.

Comment: No...I am talking about this line "Now when user run it again while server and client processes are still running, it suppose to become client". The way you are achieving this is..when user runs the program again ....you first call RegisterServer as server is already running....you get the remoting  exception then  you RegisterClient in catch block....you should add IsClient = true which is used by function to which delegate points...as IsClient not set to true....you see ISClient false in output which leds you to believe that client is not running.....

Comment: I added in the answer which will help you to understand my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate is running on server because new Client is invoking delegate of RemoteObject on server. There is no CallBack registered between server and first client. server will not know which process to callback as there is no one in first client listening to request.
Generally with technologies like WCF we can have DualHttpBindings which will allow duplex communication but here we dont have any CallBacks. So we have to registered a callback channel with RemoteObject in first client which will make sure delegate is invoked in first client process..I have tried it and it is working. I added some process ID for debugging purpose.

```
  static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName33";
            const string OBJECT_NAME = "test";
            const string CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName34";
            const string CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME = "testclient";

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if ((args.Length == 0 || args[0] == "s"))
            {
                try
                {
                   IPCRegistration.RegisterServer(PIPE_NAME,OBJECT_NAME);
                }
                catch (RemotingException)
                {
                                        remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject),PIPE_NAME,OBJECT_NAME);
                    remoteObject.OnNewProcessStarted("test");
                    Application.Exit();
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Server:" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "c");
                Application.Run(new Form1("Server"));

            }
            else
            {
                IsClient = true;
                remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject), PIPE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
                IPCRegistration.RegisterServer(CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME, CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME); // Here Client will listen on this channel.
                remoteObject.SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStarted,Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Client:" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                Application.Run(new Form1("Client"));

            }
        }


        static RemoteObject remoteObject;

        static bool IsClient = false;
        static bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("saved:"+commandLine+" Currrent:"+Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            MessageBox.Show("Is Client : " + IsClient);//problem here, IsClient should be true
            return true;
        }
    }

    public delegate bool OnNewProcessStartedDelegate(string text);

    internal class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public OnNewProcessStartedDelegate OnNewProcessStartedHandler;
        public string value;
        public bool isCallBack = false;
        const string PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName33";
        const string OBJECT_NAME = "test";
        const string CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName34";
        const string CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME = "testclient";
        RemoteObject remoteObject;
        public bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
        {
            if (!isCallBack)
            {
                remoteObject.isCallBack = true;
                return remoteObject.OnNewProcessStarted(commandLine);
            }

            if (OnNewProcessStartedHandler != null)
                return OnNewProcessStartedHandler(value);
            return false;
        }



        public void SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStartedDelegate onNewProcessStarted,string value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnNewProcessStartedHandler = onNewProcessStarted;
            if (!isCallBack)
            {
                remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject), CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME, CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME);
                remoteObject.isCallBack = true;
                remoteObject.SetOnNewProcessStarted(onNewProcessStarted, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
            }
        }

        public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    internal class IPCRegistration
    {
       public  static RemoteObject RegisterClient(Type remoteObject,string PIPE_NAME,string OBJECT_NAME)
        {
            IpcClientChannel chan = new IpcClientChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

            RemoteObject remoteObjectInstance = (RemoteObject)Activator.GetObject(remoteObject,
                    string.Format("ipc://{0}/{1}", PIPE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME));
            return remoteObjectInstance;
        }
        public static void RegisterServer(string pipeName, string objectName)
        {
            BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
            serverProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

            IpcServerChannel chan = new IpcServerChannel("", pipeName, serverProvider);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

            RemotingServices.Marshal(new RemoteObject(), objectName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not correct. Setting IsClient true for this process is not right. Because when OnNewProcessStarted() will be called, it will fire the delegate that suppose to execute in first client that was created right after the server process. Here is what is happening, when app run first time, it runs as server and also starts a new process for client. Now if any other process that will be run by user, it will just become client call OnNewProcessStarted on remote object and kill itself. While server and first client stays running. I hope I'm clear now.

Comment: "it will just become client call OnNewProcessStarted on remote object and kill itself" Here what you are doing is Getting Remoteobject by calling RegisterClient and then calling OnNewProcessStartedMethod but your isClient is static variable which will be false when run the program again..you have not set the value to true yet so when delegate is fired isClient is displayed as false

Comment: Why are you want to call OnNewProcessStart event second time? I see you immediately exit the application after that...why not just exit the application without calling OnNewProcessStart?

Comment: You seems to misunderstood the structure of app. Here I try again. User runs the app first time, app become server and start a new process as its client. Both client and server keep running. But now again, user run the app again, now since it cant be server because there already a server running. So it just become client and send a message to server and die. Server then transfer that message to the client it started. Its "client to server to client" message. But thats not happening, its becoming "client to server to server" message.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the concept of delegates...When you run your app second time it will not invoke delegate method under first client process instead it will invoke in new client process....Try this Run your app for first time..both server and client will be running then close client and run again the app now delegate of first client cannot be invoked right but you will still see the message box....you can add some more information in your message box to understand which process it is in to understand completely.I guess code is working fine only..it is NOT running under server...

Comment: What you want to achieve is completely differrent thing and cannot be accomplished with delegates....you have to use named pipes for inter process communication...that is what you are looking at.... and If your client and server are running under different server then your first client will be bind to a particular port you have send information from server to that port so that first client picks it up.....I hope you got some idea now....

Comment: Hi again Viru, please read the code I posted. I'm already using .net remoting. The delegate is being called in server, that is 100% surety. Please read about .net remoting and event. It will clear things up. Thank you :)

Comment: @J.Doe I took your code and did a little debugging and infact found out that delegate was getting invoked at server side. It seems IPC is not going to invke delegate in client process automatically. you have to come up with some kind of Callback mechanism. Please see my updated answer..I tested it and now I can see isClient true in message box as you expected.

Comment: It is working nicely. I had something similar in mind as a last resort but you have done very good. I wish I could upvote you if I had enough reputation. Thank you very much Viru and have a nice day or night.

Answer (score 0):

in the second run of the application, you don't set the delegate in the RemoteObject, so the previously set delegate object is used (it was set in the first run of your application).

I think that if you run your second application with command argument like 'c' the delegate will be run in the client process.

Comment: I do not understand your answer, delegate is supppose to execute in client process.